# How to retrieve all the historical bars

Tags: algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4, mt4

I'm building my first indicator. I want to retrieve all the historical bars of a symbol in some graphical period; in concrete in **`H1`** timeFrame.

But the next code returns very different results, depending of the `Symbol()`.

For example, for USDCHF, it returns 19752, which seems to be correct;
 but, for EURUSD, it returns only 2047, which, for me, seems rather a few bars.

`int totalBars = Bars( Symbol(), PERIOD_H1 );`

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The posted numbers seem fair

Typically, until you hit a "ceiling", pre-set in <kbd>MT4/Terminal</kbd> settings, the number of Bars changes. From small numbers up. Say from a few thousands to more than 1.000.000 bars, if one wishes ( and takes care ).

Once you are comfortable with loading OHLCV-datapoints from your Broker, there is one more speciality in how `#indicators` handle their `MQL4` code-execution, which is different from any your prior experience with `{` **`Script`** | **`ExpertAdvisor`** `}` code, but will not complicate the story right in the start.

### MQL4 (un)predictable distributed storage

Well, your next surprise for today, webmeiker

`MQL4` code cannot on it's own explicitly manage data access.

In principle, Broker defines it's data-retrieval policy. <kbd>MT4/Terminal</kbd> piece of software runs a `localhost` part of the circus.

A <kbd>Graph</kbd> constitutes a view into a (hidden) model.

<kbd>**`F2`**</kbd> may introduce you to the **`History Center`** interface, which may help you inspect how deep into past your Bar-inventory goes.

### Load 'em ALL!

Well, the *ALL* itself is not under your control.

**If and only if your Broker allows**, you may do a few tricks to receive more "historical" datapoints.

Time, as usual, works against you in this dilemma. After some time, Broker need not allow you anymore to re-load history and your "missed" part of the `OHLCV`-world will then remain un-retrievable.

So a due care is in place.

If interested in how to load more bars from your Broker, do not hesitate to raise a question on this trick.

Comment: Oughhh, I am very newbie to assimilate all this information.
I dont find the MT4/Terminal settings option to hit the ceilling preset you mentions.
Also I have no previous experience with the History Center ...

Comment: :o) hope you enjoyed the Janet Bernanke joke